# Autosize UILabels in custom style UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` with two cell prototypes. One (the first one in the screenshot above) you might recognise as the *subtitle* style standard cell. The second one is *custom*, with an extra text field.

When I run the app, the labels using the first template size their width nicely depending on the size of the text in them, whereas the one using custom template doesn't scale, effectively clipping the text after three characters.

Is there a way to configure the *custom* template in XCode Storyboard designer to size the label like the built-in *subtitle* cell template does?

[image: cell templates]

Comment: Setting suitable auto layout constraints to Cell you want to customise will make it work.

Comment: How do you set the height of each cell? I mean tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @Danyun why would that matter? I return 44 or 88 depending on the template a given cell is using (first or second respectively)

Comment: Are you taking about width or height? the problem might be different. If width probably you had set the "Title" label to a fixed width in autolayout, thus it can't express its intrinsic content size.

Comment: ah I see where the confusion was. I was talking about width. Updated the question to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Set Constraints as shown in figure

[image]

The truncated label in image (T..) is TextField.

Set Row height to minimum size for the Cell as 155.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can change the size of the label with respect to the text entered in the textfield

```
-(CGSize)frameForText:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode      
{

NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                              };
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:attributes
                                     context:nil];
return textRect.size;
}
```

Calling the Method:

```
CGSize size =[self frameForText:body sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I want to avoid having to do that in code though. Surely it must be possible to achieve that through the storyboard designer